# Creating a page for custom taxonomy archive

Tags: custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a custom taxonomy called 'news'. Inside it I have two categories called 'news-releases' and 'competition-news'.

Going to 'mydomain.com/news/competition-news' gives the expected result and displays all of the news for that category. On the page 'mydomain.com/news' I'd like to list items from both categories but at the minute I get a 404 error, I think that WordPress is probably looking for a page called news.

Is the only way to get around this to create a static page called 'news' with a custom template? Doing it this way seems a little messy and I already have a template file called taxonomy-news.php that displays the news the way I want it that I'd rather not duplicate it if possible. Even a plugin that would create this page automatically would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

That`s the suggestion: make a "news" page with a custom page template for it.
Inside there, just query your db as you need.

For the moment, i can`t find another solution.