# Custom Taxonomy - Archive for the whole Custom Taxonomy (and not just single term)?

Tags: custom-taxonomy

My question/problem is probably unclear/confusing, so here's an example what I would like to do.

I have a custom post type for recipes and a custom taxonomy for ingredients.

The following url works just fine:
mywebsite.com/recipes/ingredients/fish/

Now what I would like to have is something like
mywebsite.com/recipes/ingredients/
to show a list of the different taxonomies (ingredients).

But I just get a 404.

Somebody had a similar problem here: [Creating a page for custom taxonomy archive](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/82124/creating-a-page-for-custom-taxonomy-archive)
and solved it by creating a page. I've created a "recipes" and "ingredients" page, but still get a 404 error when opening the "/recipes/ingredients" page (guess some sort of conflict due to the same slugs).
I've also tried the different options of the template hierarchy (http://codex.wordpress.org/images/1/18/Template_Hierarchy.png), but hadn't any luck so far.

I'm not sure if it can work at all, because there's no standard "/category/" page in wordpress either. But maybe there's a way?

The code looks as follows:

```
// Register Custom Taxonomy
function ingredients() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                       => _x( 'ingredients', 'Taxonomy General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'              => _x( 'ingredient', 'Taxonomy Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'                  => __( 'ingredients', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'                  => __( 'All ingredients', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item'                => __( 'zz ingredient', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'          => __( 'zz ingredient:', 'text_domain' ),
    'new_item_name'              => __( 'new ingredient', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'               => __( 'ingredient hh', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'                  => __( 'ingredient bb', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'                => __( 'ingredients bb', 'text_domain' ),
    'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'ingredients sep', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'               => __( 'ingredients search', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_or_remove_items'        => __( 'ingredient add delete', 'text_domain' ),
    'choose_from_most_used'      => __( 'most used', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'                  => __( 'not found', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                       => 'recipes/ingredients',
    'with_front'                 => true,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'labels'                     => $labels,
    'hierarchical'               => true,
    'public'                     => true,
    'show_ui'                    => true,
    'show_admin_column'          => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
    'show_tagcloud'              => true,
    'rewrite'                    => $rewrite,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
);
register_taxonomy( 'ingredients', array( 'recipes' ), $args );}
// Register Custom Post Type
function recipes_posts() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => _x( 'recipes', 'Post Type General Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'singular_name'       => _x( 'recipe', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text_domain' ),
    'menu_name'           => __( 'recipes', 'text_domain' ),
    'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Übergeordnete recipe:', 'text_domain' ),
    'all_items'           => __( 'All recipes', 'text_domain' ),
    'view_item'           => __( 'recipe cc', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new_item'        => __( 'recipe bb', 'text_domain' ),
    'add_new'             => __( 'ww hinzuf&uuml;gen', 'text_domain' ),
    'edit_item'           => __( 'recipe zz', 'text_domain' ),
    'update_item'         => __( 'recipe uu', 'text_domain' ),
    'search_items'        => __( 'recipe ss', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found'           => __( 'not found', 'text_domain' ),
    'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'nf trash', 'text_domain' ),
);
$rewrite = array(
    'slug'                => 'recipes',
    'with_front'          => true,
    'pages'               => true,
    'feeds'               => true,
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => __( 'recipes', 'text_domain' ),
    'description'         => __( 'div. recipes.', 'text_domain' ),
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'comments', ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 10,
    'menu_icon'           => '',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => true,
    'exclude_from_search' => false,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => $rewrite,
    'capability_type'     => 'post',
);
register_post_type( 'recipes', $args );}
```

Comment: The default URLs should be mywebsite.com/recipes/ for all recipes, mywebsite.com/recipes/a-single-recipe/ for a single recipe and mywebsite.com/ingredients/fish/ for the archive of recipes with fish. If mywebsite.com/recipes/ingredients/fish/ works instead of mywebsite.com/ingredients/fish/ is beacuse there is some extra rewrite rule, which can be conflicting with the slugs of your pages. Can you post the code that register your custom post type and your custom taxonomy?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to display a listing template of a certain taxonomy?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/140470/how-to-display-a-listing-template-of-a-certain-taxonomy)

Comment: @cybmeta yes, you're right about that, I've changed the slug to have a nicer structure. However, I've tried it without this extra slug (so just "ingredients" as a slug) and got the same result). I've added the code above.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I think Shail had a similar solution, so I answered it down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create custom template and put code to get all terms for ingredient taxonomy....

Then create new page and assign new template to this page...

Thats it....

How to create template: http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Get all Terms for a specific taxonomy: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms

Comment: I've thought about that, but I couldn't get the right url to work. So ideally I would create a page called "ingredients" and have it under a parent item like "recipes". But the page "mywebsite.com/recipes/ingredients/" gives me a 404 error. But maybe it's just not possible and I need to list the terms on a different page?

Comment: And "mywebsite/recipes/" worked just fine when I've added a page called "recipes" (although it didn't load the page but the custom post type, which is great). But it didn't work with the page "/recipes/ingredients/", so I guess wordpress didn't try to load the page but just the error page instead? (if that makes any sense)

Comment: Here you are using recipes slug for page that already assigned to custom post type. So your url trying to find ingredients post in recipe section...

Comment: What i'm trying to say is in "mywebsite.com/recipes/ingredients/"  this url wordpress trying to find a recipe named ingredients. For just test create ingredients recipe in recipe section and than run this page It will work...

Comment: Try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/

Comment: You're completly right, I've added a recipe called "ingredients". I think I can work with this idea, since I'll just need to change the layout of this recipe. :) Thanks, I've struggeled with this problem for quiet some time.

Comment: Glad to help you...

Comment: And the plugin works like a charm, so now I have two available solutions. :) Edit: had some problems with the terms while using the plugin, so I'll stick to the first solution.